# TripleDES encryption using OpenSSL enc subcommand

Tags: encryption, openssl

I have a tool which is using OpenSSL for RSA and DES/TDES operation. After processing by a tool, I got `key = 4F324364970DBA5DE058EF0EAE54625E` and the encrypted data is like `data = D4B596A6724A32B4663965688F28E01C`

Here when I try online tool [DES_Calculator](http://www.emvlab.org/descalc/?key=4F324364970DBA5DE058EF0EAE54625E&iv=0000000000000000&input=D4B596A6724A32B4663965688F28E01C&mode=cbc&action=Decrypt&output=31313131313131313180000000000000) for decryption, got require plain text after decryption, what I found, need to try TDES with CBC mode.

I tried to do the same (decryption) with OpenSSL with following command:

```
 C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin>openssl enc -d -des-ede-cbc -nosalt -k 4F324364970DBA5DE058
EF0EAE54625E -iv 0000000000000000 -in ENC_DATA -out ENC_DATA_O
bad decrypt
6088:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:.\
crypto\evp\evp_enc.c:529:
```

where content of ENC_DATA is like[image: ENC_DATA]

Here I want the same result as from the online tool.

Also the same command is working fine after `-e` option performed on same set of files. Could anybody tell me why this error occurs and how to remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `-K` instead of `-k`. `-k` is used for passphrases and `-K` for keys in hexadecimals. You'd probably not require the `-nosalt` option anymore.

You need to use `-nopad` and remove the bit padding yourself.

Bit padding consists of a single bit set to 1 followed by multiple bits set to 0. If the plaintext consists of bytes - it usually does - then bit padding is equal to a single byte `80` followed by zero or more `00` valued bytes.

Nowadays PKCS#7 compatible padding is usually used. OpenSSL is only able to remove PKCS#7 padding.

Comment: tried C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin>openssl enc -d -des-ede-cbc  -K 4F324364970DBA5DE058EF0EAE5
4625E -iv 0000000000000000 -in ENC_DATA -out ENC_DATA_O
bad decrypt
6596:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:.\
crypto\evp\evp_enc.c:529:

Comment: @Arjun: Your encryption appears to have used [one-and-zeros padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29#ISO.2FIEC_7816-4) which OpenSSL does not support. You can decrypt with `openssl enc -des-ede-cbc -d -K hex -iv hex -nopad` and then remove the padding with a different tool (like perl) or manually.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks, I didn't take a look at that website. You can see the 00 valued bytes being added so I can confirm that this is what happens.

Comment: Actually it *is* bit padding, aligned to a byte boundary -- note it's one byte 80 then 6 bytes 00. (I didn't look at the website myself, just -nopad piped to hexdump.)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Then there is a difference between the site and the output of the "tool" :). Probably the 0x80 wasn't detected or printed.

Comment: Huh? the 'tool' in the message *is* the webpage `www.emvlab.org/...` which shows Output Data `31313131313131313180000000000000` which breaks up into bytes as `31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 **80** 00 00 00 00 00 00` (emphasis added) which is the same result I got running `<file openssl enc -d ... -nopad | od -tx1` on my system except the bytes are already conveniently separated.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 -nopad works here, will have to remove padding (80 00...00) from other way.